# join three tables on a condition of the thirst table

Tags: sql, join

I have a quick question

I have a table with openid's and two other tables
What connects them all is the userid

But I have to start looking for the userid in de openid table
Can this be done in one select statement or do I need two

I try'd this, but obviously diddn't work

SELECT op`*`,g`*`,gp`*` FROM `openid` AS op
INNERJOIN `users` AS g ON( g.`userid` = op.`userid`)
INNERJOIN `profiles` AS gp ON( gp.`userid` = op.`userid`)
WHERE op.`openid` = `2`

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT op.*, g.*, gp.* 
FROM openid AS op 
INNER JOIN users AS g ON g.userid = op.userid
INNER JOIN profiles AS gp ON gp.userid = op.userid
WHERE op.openid = 2
```

Comment: thanks a lot, do you know what it was, backticks or the brackets

Comment: sorry, took some time retyping the query

Comment: 2 things: you wrote `INNER JOIN` without space and your missed the `.` between `op.*, g.*, gp.*`

Comment: thanks, can I somehow get back in the result one userid column instead of three?

Comment: Yes. You can `group by`. But then you have to define what content from the other tables should be returned. In order to do that you would have to expand your question with info about the content of your tables and what exactly you want to get back.

Comment: I think I will leave it like this. I aliased one userid column so I can easyli pick it out of the resultset. Also one table is dynamic and can have all kinds of columns, but thank you for your answer